# Einstein's mass-energy relation question

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Energy can be converted into mass and mass can be converted into energy then what intermediate state between them?

Comment: Actually, it is a bit wrong to say Energy _is converted to_ mass and mass _is converted to_ Energy. But, even so why do you think there _must be_ an intermediate state?

Comment: what energy can not converted into mass?

Comment: than what this equation says e=mc^2

Comment: It says _Energy has mass_. No need for any conversion.

Comment: sir send me link  please which says that energy has mass?

Comment: The statement: _any additional energy (of any form) acquired by the object above that rest energy will increase the object's total mass just as it increases its total energy_ [in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy)

Comment: Or the statement _Similarly, anything having energy exhibits a corresponding mass $m$ given by its energy $E$ divided by the speed of light squared $c^2$_ [in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)

Comment: You just have to read the introductory pages on Wikipedia about any topic in special relativity. You will eventually find something that says the equivalent of _Energy has mass_. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that I can't comment, but the short  answer to your question is to be found in following the decay pattern of,  for example, particles produced at the LHC.  An example of this is [Atlas Experiment at CERN](https://atlas.cern/updates/physics-briefing/5-fundamental-parameters-top-quark-decay)

Intermediate and (very) temporary particles are created and in turn, they decay, until the stable particles (such as electrons and protons) appear at the end of the process.